# Intellij comment shortcut opens help tab on the Mac menu bar

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

When I use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> keyboard shortcut to `comment`/`uncomment` a block of code, the `Help` tab on the menu bar in IntelliJ also opens.

Does anyone know how to prevent this shortcut from opening the `Help` menu tab in `IntelliJ 16.1.2`? I am using the `Mac OS X 10.5+` shortcuts.

Comment: What a waste of time this... why don't they just fix this.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Remove or replace the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut in your mac. Apple menu-> System Preferences-> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

[image: ss]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped save quite some time.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I was searching the key bindings in IntelliJ and was completely confused when I couldn't find the shortcut.

Comment: Note: In macOS 14.2 and later, make sure to expand the "All Applications" menu item. I didn't notice the caret icon initially.

Answer (score 9):

Steps:

1. Remove or replace the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut on your Mac (as mentioned by @Bajal)
2. Add new Intellij shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> for "Comment with Line Comment" (Preferences -> Keymap)

[image]

Comment: You are a genius, basically is the same but for some reason intellij doesnt like command / which is bassically command shift 7

Answer (score 2):

I used this work around but it didn't fix the problem:

In  IntelliJ, I went to `Preferences` -> `Keymap` and I searched for comment. It turns out that there are 3 different commands to `comment`/`uncomment` a block of code.

1. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

My work around to prevent <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> from opening the `Help` menu tab is to use one of the other keyboard shortcuts.

This doesn't answer my question fully so if anyone has any suggestion please let me know as I would prefer to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same issue. The solution by Bajal helped, because the shortcut didn't trigger the `help` tab. But it didn't allow me to line comment my code.

So I had to add `Shift` + `Cmd` + `7` to the keymap. This is exactly the same as `Cmd` + `/`, but I had to add it anyway.

Comment: Can confirm this: `/` doesn't seem to mean `SHIFT`+`7`. IntelliJ wants you to press `SHIFT`, then with a slight delay `COMMAND`, then with a slight delay again `7` (in any order) to register `SHIFT`+`COMMAND`+`7` as the desired shortcut.