# IntelliJ shortcut to comment a line

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

There is a way in WebStorm to comment or uncomment a specific line or selected block of source code with shortcut?
I tried to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: In MAC `⌥⌘/` to comment only selected text within line, and repeat again for uncomment.

Comment: I was trying to find how I could continue commenting on the next line, and the answer is `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` for those who ended up at this question from Google

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try to use:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for Line Comment
or
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> for Block Comment
or
Set you own keyboard shortcut in Settings from `File` -> `Settings...` -> `Keymap`.
Then search for "comment".

Note: It's the numpad <kbd>/</kbd> that works.

References:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: Thanks i change this in settings page

Comment: Thanks for showing how to change it in the Keymap settings. On thing bugs me: When I comment a line, the cursor jumps to the next line. Is there a way to let the cursor stay on the same line?

Answer (score 52):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, but with the <kbd>/</kbd> located on the numpad.

Commenting with <kbd>/</kbd> (the one besides <kbd>.</kbd>) does not work for me, either).

Answer (score 10):

On Windows with a German keyboard layout the default keyboard shortcut for the comment lines action `Ctrl+/` conflicts with the bookmark shortcut `Ctrl+7`. You need to remove the keyboard shortcut for bookmarks in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 9):

On a **Mac with an extra keyboard** it is <kbd>CMD</kbd> + Numpad's <kbd>/</kbd>.
The one on the native Macbook keyboard I did not get to work.
Check this post as well: [Intellij comment shortcut opens help tab on the Mac menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144396/intellij-comment-shortcut-opens-help-tab-on-the-mac-menu-bar)

Answer (score 9):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> ==> To comment/uncomment a line .
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> ==> To comment/uncomment block of code.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> ==> To delete a line.

Comment: I din't understand.

Comment: In a Mac replace `Ctrl` with `Cmd`.

Answer (score 7):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> doesn't work , try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Num Pad <kbd>/</kbd>.
You can check the exact configuration in settings->keymap.

Answer (score 7):

@Note Shortcut IntelliJ IDEA

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> => comment or uncomment a line -> `//`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> => comment or uncomment block of code -> `/**/`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> => delete a line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> => duplicate a line

Answer (score 4):

I have an AZERTY keypad in French, so this was the answer for me :

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `/` **on the numpad**

Because `/` out of the numpad was detected as `:`, even with `Caps Lock` on.

You can check how the keystrokes are actually detected by IntelliJ in :

**On Windows :**
`Settings` > `Keymap` > click on the icon of *Magnifying glass with cubes* (tooltip is "Find Actions By Shortcut"). In the little tooltip that opens, you stroke the keys and observe the registered results.

**On Ubuntu :**
`Settings` > `Keymap` > click on the icon of *Keyboard*, right next to the search input (tooltip is "Find Actions By Shortcut"). In the little tooltip that opens, you stroke the keys and observe the registered results.

Comment: Yeah, this is really annoying!

Answer (score 3):

Commenting out each line of selected code for Mac users **without numpad** would have to add a keyboard shortcut:

1. Navigate to settings: Preferences > Keymap > Main menu > Code
2. Double click on `Comment with Line Comment`
3. Insert your shortcut, for example: `cmd + shift + 7` would be interpreted as `shift + cmd + 7` but works the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate this option:

- '*Settings*' > '*Keymap*' > '*Use national layouts for shortcuts (requires restart)*'

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

As said before on Mac Montery 12
on Idea 2020.3

***CMD*** + ***NumPad /***

or from Action dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to switch to the English layout

Answer (score 0):

its possible to use inellij IDEA by the way you customized before with an IDE like VisualStudio
Settings -> KeyMap -> Choose your old IDE its a grate! feature life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

try ctrl + shift + 7 or num lock and then ctrl + /

Comment: This answer does not contribute anything new to the topic. Please check the other answers to see if your answer offers any new information before posting

Answer (score 0):

control + /  (this is the mathematical one which is located on the numbad)

Answer (score -1):

Use the English keyboard, the problem will be solved easily

Comment: HI @Hamid Hamid Abulqasemi, your answer seems to be unclear. Please explain in little more detail. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer